# Is it possible to inject css into standard Salesforce pages

Tags: css, standardcontroller

Our designer wants to change the look and feel of the header and sidebar of the salesforce pages including standard ones. I can't think of the way of injecting css code into standard pages. Is that possible?

Comment: Do not do this...even though if you want to change the standard one then you disable the inclusion of the Salesforce stylesheets, only your custom stylesheets will affect the styling of the page. Salesforce stylesheets are not versioned, and the appearance and class names of components may change without notice. Some more info  here http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_styling_salesforce.htm

Comment: @KiranMutturu, yep, I said the same thing to my designers and they said they are willing to take the risk.

Comment: if it is a risk then we can definitely give a try, but if we know that this risk is a repetitive risk then we  should think before we do that. As I said earlier , Your team should stop the standard stylesheets completely or need to mimic the custom CSS to load on top of standard CSS which is a repetitive risky task because Salesforce may change the CSS names or completely remove those components without any notice. This may be a justification from your end...If still they want to do this then those people will be in the History for ever.....